# How to select a query for a selected day[2010-11-04] to present date using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

How can i display the data from a select query from 2010-11-04 onwards to till date using MYSQL

```
Table : Stu_Details

sl.no name status address created_date
110   soul   1    add      2010-09-01
111   saul   1    add      2010-10-01
112   seth   1    add      2010-10-04//starting date
113   ray    1    add      2010-10-06
114   james  1    add      2010-10-07
115   ram    1    add      2010-10-05
----
115   prem   1    add      2011-11-21//till date

Output

sl.no name status address created_date
112   seth   1    add      2010-10-04
113   ray    1    add      2010-10-06
114   james  1    add      2010-10-07
115   ram    1    add      2010-10-05
----
115   prem   1    add      2011-11-21//till date
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM Stu_Details 
   WHERE created_date >= '2010-10-04'
ORDER BY created_date
```

Comment: previous one was correct coz it would used to search for the present day , i guess no need of AND created_date <= '2011-11-21'

Comment: @soul Yes, if you are looking for up to the current date, then you don't need the `AND` clause. I am taking it off.

Comment: @soul if u are searching based on present day u can use `DATE(now())` instead of `2011-11-21`

Comment: @shef I know its implied, but I have made some silly errors when having some dates ahead of Today's date.

Comment: @Shirish11 Yeah, nice point. It depends on the data, if the OP is sure there won't be dates in the future there is no need. Otherwise an `AND` or `BTWEEN` clause should be included in the query. :)

Answer (score 2):

A simple `where` would do the trick?

```
select  *
from    Stu_Details
where   '2010-10-04' <= created_date and created_date < '2011-11-21'
```

Comment: i guess no need of AND created_date <= '2011-11-21' in order to get the details till date

Answer (score 0):

WHERE

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Stu_Details
where   created_date >= '2010-10-04' ORDER BY `created_date` ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from table where date BETWEEN '2010-10-4' and ('2010-10-4' + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

I am INTERVAL is simply string edition and calculations. simply MySQL will do this.